# Create Table from SUM of values from other tables

Tags: datatable, powerbi, dax, measure

I have created measures called prev1, prev2, cur1, cur2 which are sum of numbers.
Then I created a table called using "Enter Data" button.
In the first column I have entered Item_A, Item_B

I am trying to acheive the below:

```
Col1 PREV CUR
------ ---- -----
Item_A Prev1 Cur1
Item_B Prev2 Cur2
```

E.g.:

```
Col1 PREV CUR
------ ---- -----
Item_A 123 312
Item_B 213 132
```

I tried the below but it gave me a very large number.

```
PREV = SWITCH([Col1], Item_A", [Prev1])
```

Also tried this but its the same large number even when I try with CALCULATE

```
PREV = sumx(FooBar, [Prev1])
```

This may be becasue I have slicers and it ignores the filter context from those slicers. So I have tried ALLSELECTED() but it does not change the figures on a measure:

```
CALCULATE(sum(Cur1), ALLSELECTED())
```

Please can someone enlighten me.

---

EDIT 1:

I have just rechecked my data and the problem is as I am suspected that it does not apply the FILTER CONTEXT from the report.

EDIT 2:
I have manged to get the figure that I am after using the below but its hard coded:
calculate(SUM(Cur), Date = date(2019,4,22))

When I then use the below code to automate that I see no figure at all:
calculate(SUM(Cur), Date = SELECTEDVALUE(date, ""))

So now I think if I can convert the returning value {SELECTEDVALUE(date, "")} to date that might work but how should I do that?

Comment: Remove the alternate result (" ") from selectedvalue, it is converting the output to type text

Comment: Thanks @PratikBhavsar but that didn't work too but I have just figured it out and posted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have finally got the this:

```
calculate(
    SUM(cur), 
    filter(
        myTable, 
        dateID = related(dateID)
    )
)
```

So, I am making sure that the value is calculated by complying to the relationship between the two tables. This way I am making sure that FILTER CONTEXT is intact.

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate calculation for cur and prev measures? 
From what I understand, you can do the following:

```
SUMMARIZE (
    Items,
    Items[Col1],
    "Prev", SUM(Items[Prev]) //Or your calculation,
    "Cur", SUM(Items[Cur]) //Or your calculation
)
```

Comment: your answer gives me the same output as the ones I have tried. Cur is a value coming directly from the table and prev is a measure that is sum with conditions.

Comment: Here is main logic from the measure: calculate(SUM(cur), DATEADD(Date, -7, DAY))

Comment: @Unbound verify you relationships

Comment: @Patik just rechecked and it's looking fine. The other parts of the report is working fine as well. Also surely found out that the FILTER CONTEXT is not being applied but not sure how to achieve that.

Comment: @Unbound are both col1 and cur from same table?

Comment: As described col1  is my manual input. I have just appended my latest finding. Please read the Edits in the original post.